# broadleafcommerce with tomcat10 standalone

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, war, tomcat10

Is there somewhere an example of web.xml and content.xml to use broadleafcommerce with tomcat(10) standalone ?
I do not know how to make it work.I need help in doing this thing.

Deploy admin.war, site.war and api.war on tomcat10 standalone.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the README of Broadleaf demoSite ?

- https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/DemoSite/

Comment: Yes i have already it

Comment: When standalone tomcat10 is stopped, java -jar admin.war (and api.war and site.war) are ok.

Comment: When standalone tomcat10 is running and when i go to page administration of tomcat no application (api admin or site) can be launched. i guess i must suppress tomcat embedded which conflicts with standalone tomcat10. Is it the good way ?